# Tools to capture web service traffic

Tags: asp.net, web-services, firebug, fiddler, web-traffic

We are working on ASP.NET application that calls external web services and I need to look through the requests that are made by the .net application. I know firebug and fiddler are used for this purpose. But my application doesn't support firefox and for fiddler to work, I realized I need to do proxy settings on the server which is not feasible for me.

So, I would like to know if there are any tools out there to capture the traffic without additional configuration and works with IE.

Comment: Is the asp.net site making the calls to the external webservice by using an WCF client?

Comment: It is calling web API services

Comment: That is not an answer to my question. Are you using Windows Communication Foundation to communicate with that external web service? See if anything of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms731082(v=vs.90).aspx) looks familiar  to stuff you have in your application....

Comment: Why can you not configure your asp.net application to call through a proxy?

Answer (score -1):

Use Google analytic tool.once you register with it it will Crete j's file.put this code snippet into asp or view.

Comment: I don't see how installing google analytics will solve the vague problem of the OP...